# EF Core 7 getting all grandchildren

Tags: ef-core-7.0

I have a data structure (SQL Server) with `Parent`, `Child` and `Grandchild` tables (one to many relationships between them). My model includes the navigation properties, so it is easy to start with the parent and then present each child and each set of grandchildren in that way.

My problem is that I present the grandchildren by category which does not relate to the child table, but the grandchildren are not directly related to the parent table. So what I do is given a selected child (`mychild`), I get all of the children that share that parent:

```
var childIdList = child.Where(parentId = mychild.parentID)
                       .Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
```

Then I loop through this list and get the grandchildren, adding them to a list:

```
foreach (id in childIdList) 
{
    var glist = grandkids.Where(childId == id)
                         .Include(g => g.Notes);
    mainList.AddRange(glist);
}
```

I can't find a better way to do this, and currently I have a linq-to-SQL that calls a stored procedure I wrote to do this (it joins several tables though, this example is far simpler).

Is there an EF method that can make this "simpler"? I don't want to get the grandkids as lists under the children. I want to start with a child, and get all of the grandkids that the selected child's parent has, and present all of these grandkids grouped into categories along with any and all notes (which is another one to many with the grandkids) for them as well.

I could create an entity for the return type of the stored procedure, but I am trying to move away from that for easier maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried eliminating the loop eg

```cs
var mainList = grandkids.Where(g => childIdList.Contains(g.ChildId))
                         .Include(g => g.Notes).ToList();
```

It's difficult to answer without having the real code. If you are calling stored procedures in loops, you might also want to look at table-valued parameters?

Comment: ah, this is good . . . I had not found the syntax for the contains check there . . . I'll try it.

Comment: Also, what size are we looking at? And what's the type of `ChildId`? If `childIdList` has many many items it might cause trouble. If that's an issue, splitting the list in smaller chunks could be a solution. Or, using a table-valued parameter or resorting to a temporary table maybe...

Comment: For any parent I expect there to be anywhere from 25-100 children, and then another 10 grandchildren or so per child.  I will have hundreds of parents overall, but the actual size on disk of the database should not be very big (just text, no images or media). @d-markey

Answer (score -1):

To improve the performance of the provided code, you can try using the Join method in LINQ to join the Child and Grandchild tables on their respective foreign keys. This will allow you to retrieve the grandchildren for a selected child's parent directly, without having to loop through a list of child IDs. Here's an example:

```
var grandkidsByCategory = from c in context.Child
                      join g in context.Grandchild on c.Id equals g.ChildId
                      where c.ParentId == mychild.ParentId
                      group g by g.Category into gGroup
                      select new
                      {
                          Category = gGroup.Key,
                          Grandkids = gGroup.ToList()
                      };

foreach (var category in grandkidsByCategory)
{
    var grandkids = category.Grandkids.Include(g => g.Notes);
    mainList.AddRange(grandkids);
}
```

This code uses the Join method to join the Child and Grandchild tables on their respective foreign keys. It then filters the results to only include grandchildren that belong to the selected child's parent. Finally, it groups the grandchildren by category and adds them to the mainList along with their notes.

Comment: The linq syntax is approximating my stored procedure here, which I have done in other cases.  Interestingly I did not know I could then go back and include the notes in a separate loop.  Nice tip :)